# How to use xlsxwriter library in a CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake

I installed xlsxwriter library with `brew install xlsxwriter`, which adds the library to the system: `/usr/local/lib/libxlsxwriter.dylib` and the header (a symlink) to `/usr/local/include/xlsxwriter.h`.
Then, I have the following minimal CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
project(main)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
find_library(XLSXWRITER_LIB xlsxwriter)
message(${XLSXWRITER_LIB})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${XLSXWRITER_LIB})
```

I can verify by the message that the system correctly finds the library.
Then, to test, I have this minimum main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <xlsxwriter.h>

int main() { return 0; }
```

However, trying to run it produces the following error:

```
fatal error: 'xlsxwriter.h' file not found
```

Can anyone help me see what I'm not doing right?

Comment: I don't think find_library is what you want. It should instead be `find_package(XlsxWriter REQUIRED)`

Comment: `target_link_libraries` only effects linker settings, it has nothing to do with adding extra include locations.

Comment: `target_link_libraries()` will set the include directory if a target is found and has the properties set for include directories which can be set using target_include_directories() in this case it would likely be an imported target you import in a finder using find_package

Comment: I see... thanks... target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "/usr/local/include/") solved the problem. However, I thought this basic path would be included by default..

Comment: There is disagreement on whether `/usr/local` should be considered by "the system" by default in general. Red Hat considers it "the place where vendor software resides", and has a couple of valid points to make with regards to system safety / security favoring *not* looking there unless explicitly instructed to do so. So directories like `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib` or (in your case) `/usr/local/include` not being considered by default tends to happen. Similar, by the way, to `/opt/...`. So, not something specific to CMake, but part of a greater disagreement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libxlsxwriter ships with a pkg-config file, so you can just use the PkgConfig module:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(Xlsxwriter REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET xlsxwriter)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC PkgConfig::Xlsxwriter)
```

This automatically sets up the linker path, linker libraries, and include path for you.